# Saving Object with embedded objects/documents in rails with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

So I have a new rails project and I have created a few classes which i have listed below.
My issue is when trying to create a "Skabelon" in my controller it fails with "ArgumentError (Wrong number of arguments (Given 2, expected 0..1))

I have my controller below as well included a small example of how the json data is being from the frontend.
Ps. I have to do this with embedded_in instead of has_many because I don't want all these to have their own collections

Skabelon.rb

```
class Skabelon
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in collection: 'skabeloner'

  field :title, type: String
  embeds_many :sektioner, class_name: "Sektion"

end
```

sektion.rb

```
class Sektion
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title

  embeds_many :felter, class_name: "SektionFelt"
  embedded_in :skabelon

end
```

sektion_felt.rb

```
class SektionFelt
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :type
  field :text
  field :felter
  embedded_in :sektion

end
```

Then i have the following controller:
The method being called is "create" from a post request sent by the frontend

```
class SkabelonController < ApplicationController

  # GET /skabeloner
  def index
    render json: Skabelon.all
  end

  # GET /skabeloner/1
  def show
    render json: Skabelon.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /skabeloner
  def create
    skabelon = Skabelon.new(skabelon_params)
    skabelon.save

  end

  # PATCH/PUT /skabeloner/1
  def update
   
  end

  # DELETE /skabeloner/1
  def destroy
  end

  private
    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.

  def skabelon_params
    params.permit!
  end

end
```

JSON from client to server:

```
 skabelon: {
        title: 'Oplysninger om barnet',
        sektioner: [{
          felter: [{type: 'text', text: 'Name'}]
}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have several problems. First it looks like you're trying to assign the wrong part of the JSON. I.e. you are passing JSON that has a top level `skabelon` property. That is what you are likely wanting to assign to the new Skabelon instance.

```
skabelon = Skabelon.new(skabelon_params[:skabelon])
```

Secondly your `sektioner` and `felter` properties are misnamed in the JSON. Since they are marked as `embeds_many` they need to be plural: `sektioners` and `felters`.

Comment: Hi thank you for the help. It seems you were right about me not looking in the right level of the JSON. 

Now i get no errors, but it only saves the top level "Skabelon" and all the embedded objected are not saved in the database any ideas?

Comment: Ive been fiddling for a while and now I am stuck on: NoMethodError (undefined method `_association' for #<ActionController::Parameters

I don't know if this is the reason why only the top level is saved

Comment: You can try specifying the strong parameters directly. e.g. `params.permit(skabelon: [:title, sketioners: [felters: [:type, :text]]])`